# How to add custom links to individual images on Advanced Custom Fields Gallery?

Tags: wordpress, gallery, advanced-custom-fields, elementor

I currently have a single post template created in Elementor where I have 2 banner images on a slider that is using Elementor's Image Carousel widget. The image source is dynamic, coming from the ACF Gallery custom field. Now, I wanted to hyperlink individual images to pages/external URLs.

I have installed this plugin called WP Gallery Custom Links and it only works if I create and insert the image gallery in Wordpress content editor but not in Advanced Custom Field Gallery.

For example, Banner 1 should link to http://yahoo.com and Banner 2 should link to http://google.com

Below are 2 screenshots to better explain the Wordpress and Elementor backend setup. Thank you for all the help in advance!

[Screenshot 1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/YAJfj.png)

[Screenshot 2](https://i.stack.imgur.com/UjyZu.png)

Comment: Do you have the access or ability to change the theme code that outputs the images in the gallery?

Comment: @johnnyd23 No i dont